# Detect empty list vs list of empty strings

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, empty-list

I am new to Python, and I have searched for solution for detecting empty list. Say we have an empty string, like:

```
a = ''
if not a:
    print('a is empty')
```

This works fine. However, my problem arises when:

```
a = ['','','']
if not a:
    print('a is empty')
```

This one does not work. What is the Pythonic way of detecting a which I guess is a list containing empty strings in the above case?

Thanks in advance for your comments and suggestions.

Comment: A list containing empty strings is not an empty list.

Comment: BTW, "does not work" is _not_ a good description. You need to tell us what happens when you run the code, eg "it doesn't print anything".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list is only empty if it has no members. It has members, but they're empty, it still has members, [so it's still truthy](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations).

---

If you want to test whether all of the members of a list are empty, you can write it like this:

```
if all(not element for element in a):
    print('a is made of empty things')
```

The [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function should be pretty obvious. The argument to it might not be. It's a generator expression—if you've never seen one, first read about [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), then [iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) and the following two sections.

---

Or you can turn it around and test whether not any of the members are not empty:

```
if not any(a):
    print('a is made of empty things')
```

The double negative seems a bit harder to understand. But on the other hand, it means you don't need to understand a generator expression (because `(element for element in a)` is just the same thing as `a`, so we can keep it simple).

(And, as PM 2Ring points out, this one probably a little faster, although probably not enough to matter for most uses.)

Comment: I bet the `not any(a)` version runs faster, but I guess the speed difference will be minimal unless `a` is large.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yeah, probably. Obviously there's more overhead from calling `not` N times instead of 1, plus the overhead of iterating N steps through a list through a generator instead of directly. I'd guess it's a constant multiplier (for large enough N, all empty) that's on the order of a few milliseconds difference for 1M, so if you had to do that for millions of lists, it would definitely be worth testing…

Comment: @PM2Ring Oh, and of course those million lists would have to mostly be all empty, so you didn't just short-circuit out of all the loops quickly.

Comment: For the OP (or anyone else with the same question), I was tempted to show how to extend this recursively, but YAGNI. But if you _do_ need it, ask. (And I promise not to explain why you can just `if True:` unless you use a non-well-founded set theory or one with ur-elements.)